# Different results from calculator and javascript ? which one is correct?

Tags: javascript

For example,

```
var a  = 62*2.9
console.log(a);
```

which returns `179.79999999999998`

but, calculator giving `179.8` accurate results. why?

Comment: It's just rounded

Comment: Look up floating point arithmatic for javascript.

Comment: @Marco_Salerno No its not. 62 * 2.9 = 179.8

Comment: but....people wants the accurate result what should be given from calc right?

Comment: Its a loophole or javascript which brings correct result?

Comment: @Satzz For that you can check out [How to deal with floating point number precision in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript).

Comment: @Satzz This is how math involving decimals works in virtually all programming languages, not just JavaScript. You need to round your numbers when you display them to the user, specifying the precision you want.